# How to find the maximum and minimum radius of the circular table in this question?

Tags: geometry

Question :- A circular table is pushed against the corner of a cuboidal room.  A point on the periphery of the circle is 9 metres away from one wall and 8 metres away from the other wall.  Find the difference between the maximum and minimum possible radius of the table.

---

I am not able to visualize how the different radius would come in the above conditions , please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The equation of the circle is $(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$.
Point $(9,8)$ lies on the circle, so setting $x=9, y=8,$ leads to
$$r^2-34r+145=0.$$
Both solutions are positive, hence giving us the maximum as well as minimum possible size of the table.